# My laptop not showing dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, reboot

Im using dell vostro 3546. Just before i was install successfully ubuntu. Before it has windows8.1. Now i did restart my laptop and doesnt showing dual boot and it showing only ubuntu. I donot know how to resolve this issue. Please help me